# Heroku deploy failure: Invalid: lock file's typescript@5.1.6 does not satisfy typescript@4.9.5

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm, heroku

I am attempting to deploy a new version of a reactjs project to heroku - I have deployed hundreds of times with no errors but now it fails every time no matter what I try to change / update.

This is the error I am getting when the deploy fails:
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's typescript@5.1.6 does not satisfy typescript@4.9.5

I have confirmed that typescript is installed in my package-lock file @4.9.5, I do not understand why I am still getting this error when I do not have typescript@5.1.6 in my lock file anywhere.

This is typescript in my node_modules

```
{
    "name": "typescript",
    "author": "Microsoft Corp.",
    "homepage": "https://www.typescriptlang.org/",
    "version": "4.9.5",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "description": "TypeScript is a language for application scale JavaScript development",
    "keywords": [
        "TypeScript",
        "Microsoft",
        "compiler",
        "language",
        "javascript"
    ],
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript.git"
    },
    "main": "./lib/typescript.js",
    "typings": "./lib/typescript.d.ts",
    "bin": {
        "tsc": "./bin/tsc",
        "tsserver": "./bin/tsserver"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=4.2.0"
    },
    "files": [
        "bin",
        "lib",
        "!lib/enu",
        "LICENSE.txt",
        "README.md",
        "SECURITY.md",
        "ThirdPartyNoticeText.txt",
        "!**/.gitattributes"
    ],
    "devDependencies": {
        "@octokit/rest": "latest",
        "@types/chai": "latest",
        "@types/fancy-log": "^2.0.0",
        "@types/fs-extra": "^9.0.13",
        "@types/glob": "latest",
        "@types/gulp": "^4.0.9",
        "@types/gulp-concat": "latest",
        "@types/gulp-newer": "latest",
        "@types/gulp-rename": "latest",
        "@types/gulp-sourcemaps": "latest",
        "@types/merge2": "latest",
        "@types/microsoft__typescript-etw": "latest",
        "@types/minimist": "latest",
        "@types/mkdirp": "latest",
        "@types/mocha": "latest",
        "@types/ms": "latest",
        "@types/node": "latest",
        "@types/source-map-support": "latest",
        "@types/which": "^2.0.1",
        "@types/xml2js": "^0.4.11",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.33.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.33.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/utils": "^5.33.1",
        "azure-devops-node-api": "^11.2.0",
        "chai": "latest",
        "chalk": "^4.1.2",
        "del": "^6.1.1",
        "diff": "^5.1.0",
        "eslint": "^8.22.0",
        "eslint-formatter-autolinkable-stylish": "^1.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^39.3.6",
        "eslint-plugin-local": "^1.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-no-null": "^1.0.2",
        "fancy-log": "latest",
        "fs-extra": "^9.1.0",
        "glob": "latest",
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-concat": "latest",
        "gulp-insert": "latest",
        "gulp-newer": "latest",
        "gulp-rename": "latest",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "latest",
        "merge2": "latest",
        "minimist": "latest",
        "mkdirp": "latest",
        "mocha": "latest",
        "mocha-fivemat-progress-reporter": "latest",
        "ms": "^2.1.3",
        "node-fetch": "^3.2.10",
        "source-map-support": "latest",
        "typescript": "^4.8.4",
        "vinyl": "latest",
        "which": "^2.0.2",
        "xml2js": "^0.4.23"
    },
    "overrides": {
        "es5-ext": "0.10.53"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "gulp runtests-parallel --light=false",
        "test:eslint-rules": "gulp run-eslint-rules-tests",
        "build": "npm run build:compiler && npm run build:tests",
        "build:compiler": "gulp local",
        "build:tests": "gulp tests",
        "start": "node lib/tsc",
        "clean": "gulp clean",
        "gulp": "gulp",
        "lint": "gulp lint",
        "setup-hooks": "node scripts/link-hooks.mjs"
    },
    "browser": {
        "fs": false,
        "os": false,
        "path": false,
        "crypto": false,
        "buffer": false,
        "@microsoft/typescript-etw": false,
        "source-map-support": false,
        "inspector": false
    },
    "packageManager": "npm@8.15.0",
    "volta": {
        "node": "14.20.0",
        "npm": "8.15.0"
    }
}
```

I have attempted deleting my package-lock file and node_modles folder and reinstalling all packages - did not work.

I tried running npm audit fix --force... no luck here either.

npm ci & npm ci --force do not fix the issue.

I have also even tried upgrading typescript to 5.1.6 and still no luck.

Seams that no matter what I try heroku will not let me deploy.

Comment: Was able to solve the issue by including npm version in package.engines:

"engines": {
    "node": "16.x",
    "npm": "8.1.2"
  },